# What determines whether a cell divides by Mitosis or Meiosis?

Tags: cell-biology, meiosis, mitosis

What I learn from biology class is that mitosis is for producing somatic cells in animals and the gametes of some plants. And meiosis is for production of animal's gametes.

I am curious about what determines whether it divides by mitosis or meiosis.
What signal does it need before it starts mitosis or meiosis?